# Fail to compile for the cause of \par in text when using \pgfsetfillopacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, spacing, xparse

I construct a macro to give text a feature of `opacity` with `\pgfsetfillopacity` from `tikz`.
It works all right except that when the second argument contains `\par` which causes the .tex file fail to compile. Why and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz,xparse}
\geometry{showframe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\opacity}{g g}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
        {\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}
      }%
      {\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}#2\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\opacity{0.5}{some text\par some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text \\some text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\NewDocumentCommand{\opacity}{g +g}`. P.S.: Don't use `g` :)

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you! And is there a way to use `\long` in the common Latex `\newcommand`

Comment: `\newcommand` creates `\long` commands by default: you actually have to use `\newcommand*` to create _non-`\long`_ commands.  But with `\newcommand` you have all arguments `\long`, or none `\long`. You could use `\NewDocumentCommand{\opacity}{m +m}` to have `xparse` and avoid `g` (in case you don't know, `m` is a mandatory argument, and `g` is an optional argument delimited by `{...}`: a really bad idea :).

Comment: @lyl `\newcommand` is `\long` already.  If you want to avoid `\long`, use `\newcommand*`.

Comment: Thank you all so much for these good information and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phelype's suggestion of using `{g +g}` is just too easy a way to fix the problem.  Since I often reinvent the wheel for fun, here is a way to search through the argument for `\par` and apply `\opacity` to each paragraph-length section of the input.  I call it `\oparcity`, to consummate the PhARce.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,tikz,xparse}
\geometry{showframe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\opacity}{g g}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
        {\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}
      }%
      {\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}#2\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}%
}

\long\def\oparcity#1#2{\iftrue\def\opvalue{#1}\oppar#2\par\fi}
\long\def\oppar#1\par#2\fi{\fi
  \opacity{\opvalue}{#1}\ifx\relax#2\relax\else\par\oppar#2\fi}

\begin{document}
\oparcity{0.5}{some text\par some text some text some text 
some text some text some text some\\ 
text some text some text \\some text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why, oh why? ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Because I still have not mastered `\NewDocumentCommand` syntax